# Build online audio library with ASP.Net + SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio-streaming

I need some advice on what is the best practice to build an online audio library with ASP.Net + C# + MSSQL. Some key requirements are as follows:

1. The audio files are stored in database in binary type
2. On the web UI, user can click on an audio icon to play the audio. The audio will be very short, a few secs max, so there is no need to provide controls except and "play" button. 
   For playing audio, I don't want to launch a media player explicitly. I just want user to click and s/he will hear the sound.
   In addition, I want to stream the audio and I don't want user to be able to download the audio file.

Can anyone shed some light on how to implement this, in particular the playing audio part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [jQuery Media Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/). It's freakin awesome!

I would then create an .ashx handler for playing the audio files, and pass those to the media plugin in jQuery.

You can follow this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/VideoUploaderControl.aspx), it shows you how to do just about everything you need, except they upload videos. You can easily tweak the code to allow JUST audio though.

It sounds like a very fun project, good luck!